# routing dynamic or basic for Nuxt js Routing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vuejs2, nuxt.js

which good for choosing to route in Next js for route only `Home`, `Gallery` and `Contact us` ?? should i use dynamic for it ? or just basic? any idea for path them? I still learning so, I do like get some idea, I have read some articles on google also, mostly they just home and about, :D for Nuxt js
or any article to read it ?? please link it :D

is that right qw do not create Vue.use(router) on any component files in webpack of nuxt js ?

could i use this ?

```
router: {
  routes: [
    {
      name: 'index',
      path: '/',
      component: 'pages/index.vue'
    },
    {
      name: 'About',
      path: '/About',
      component: 'pages/about/index.vue'
    },
    {
      name: 'Contact-us',
      path: '/user/contact',
      component: 'pages/user/contact.vue'
    }
  ]
}
```

i do like someome to fix it if incorrect

Answer (score 1):

Welcome on SO, to achieve your sent example you simply need the following Structure in your `Pages` Folder (if you use the standard nuxt setup).

```
pages/
  index.vue
  about.vue
  user/
      contact.vue
```

But to be honest if you really googled and informed yourself or even flew over the docs you would know how the Router in Nuxt works. Here I link you the well written Docs again, I hope you will read them carefully and be able to achieve good results. https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, i do read it again and agaoin :D @Badgy